# Not installing pygame in pycharm

Tags: python, php, linux, pygame, pycharm

When I am trying to install pygame in pycharm I getting this error please help me[help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMkgQ.jpg)

Comment: Please follow the [contribution guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask a good question. Please do not post images of error messages.

Comment: Do not post screenshots of the code or error trace. Paste it in the question. Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) and [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score -1):

To fix this you will have to:

1. Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"` )
2. And then via the terminal type `brew install sdl`
3. Go back to PyCharm and try installing it

Answer (score -1):

1. Open pycharm
2. click on File -> settings -> project -> project interpreter -> click on "+"
   -> search "pygame" on search bar -> install package

   **Try it**